# How to convert base64 string to sha256?

Tags: java, base64

I have my base64:

```
 String myBase64 ="MSBtZV9yYW5nZT0xNiBjaHJvbWFfbWU9MSB0cmVsbGlzPTEgOHg4ZGN0PTEgY3FtPTAgZGV";
```

How convert this base64 String to sha256?

Comment: What have you tried?  Post it and people may be able to help

Comment: What do you mean by "convert … to sha256"? SHA256 is a digest, not a format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sha-256 is a hashing algorithm. Use following to create a hash of your base 64 string:

```
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] myHashBytes = digest.digest(myBase64.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

You can again base64 encode the hash bytes to get a hash string:

```
String myHash = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(myHashBytes);
```